# Java Generics 'Incompatible Type' Compile-Time Error

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

For a CS class I am writing a linked list implementation of a linked list interface created by my professor.  The assignment requires us to use generics for the list.  What I have created, I think, is pretty standard.

```
public class MyLinkedList<T> implements ADTListInterface {
    ...
    private class Node<T> {
        Node<T> head;
        Node<T> prev;
        public Node(int max) {

        ...

        }

        public void shift() {
            ...
            Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(this.max);
            newNode.prev = head.prev;
            ...
        }

    }

    ...

}
```

At compile time following error is generated:

```
MyLinkedList.java:111: incompatible types
   found   : MyLinkedList<T>.Node<T>
   required: MyLinkedList<T>.Node<T>
newNode.prev = head.prev;
```

This error has me very confused.  Can anyone explain to me what the issue is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is probably the problem:

```
private class Node<T> {
```

The `<T>` is causing extra problems.  Because `Node` is an inner class, it doesn't need to declare its generic type again.

You should declare the `Node` class like below:

```
public class MyLinkedList<T> implements ADTListInterface {
...
private class Node {
    Node head;
    Node prev;
    public Node(int max) {

    ...
}
```